# Mysqldump and --where not compatible with "<" and ">", how to do?

Tags: php, mysql

That, it's OK:

```
exec("C:/wamp/bin/mysql/mysql5.6.17/bin/mysqldump.exe --host=".$host." --user=".$username." --password=".$password." ".$db." ".$table." --where=date_timestamp=1432883235 > ".$rep_local.$file." ");
```

That (--where=date_timestamp>1432883235) , it's not OK:

```
exec("C:/wamp/bin/mysql/mysql5.6.17/bin/mysqldump.exe --host=".$host." --user=".$username." --password=".$password." ".$db." ".$table." --where=date_timestamp>1432883235 > ".$rep_local.$file." ");
```

Because ">" it's for my file out. How can I do?

I already tried it:

```
exec("C:/wamp/bin/mysql/mysql5.6.17/bin/mysqldump.exe --host=".$host." --user=".$username." --password=".$password." ".$db." ".$table." --where="date_timestamp>1432883235" > ".$rep_local.$file." ");
```

But I have an error "unexpected date_timestamp"

And tried it:

```
exec("C:/wamp/bin/mysql/mysql5.6.17/bin/mysqldump.exe --host=".$host." --user=".$username." --password=".$password." ".$db." ".$table." -w"date_timestamp>1432883235" > ".$rep_local.$file." ");
```

Thank you so much for your help...

Comment: PLEASE TRY THIS: - `exec("C:/wamp/bin/mysql/mysql5.6.17/bin/mysqldump.exe --host=".$host." --user=".$username." --password=".$password." ".$db." ".$table." 
 -where=".date_timestamp > 1432883235 ." > ".$rep_local.$file." ");`

Comment: Or `exec("C:/wamp/bin/mysql/mysql5.6.17/bin/mysqldump.exe --host=".$host." --user=".$username." --password=".$password." ".$db." ".$table." 
 -where=".strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s')) > 1432883235 ." > ".$rep_local.$file." ");` because  you stated error `unexpected date_timestamp`

Comment: Please try and tell which is working for you?

Comment: First: unexpected '"'
Second: date_timestamp it is a variable in my database !

Comment: without getting value of `date_timestamp` how can you use it directly?

Comment: Because "where" permit to choose which column I want !
Like this example with "date_column "
https://www.percona.com/forums/questions-discussions/mysql-and-percona-server/7549-mysqldump-with-where-condition-and-date-range
Or like this with " --where="user='jimf'" "
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_where

Comment: enclose the column name with back-ticks (`\``). It'll probably work like that (haven't tested). Anyway, just go through the whole statements and make sure you enclose all column names, special characters etc. with (double) quotes, or escape them when appropriate. If you're doubting, try to execute a query with the relevant where-clause directly on your database first. That'll help you to spot any errors in the clause itself.

Comment: If I put back-ticks like that:
--where='date_timestamp' > 1432883235 
It understant ">" like output file ... 
When I execute in my console in phpmyadmin, it works... because it haven't output file in my sql console

Comment: I find the response !!! 

It was "^" just before ">":

    --where=date_timestamp^>1433510367

    exec("C:/wamp/bin/mysql/mysql5.6.17/bin/mysqldump.exe --host=".$host." --user=".$username." --password=".$password." ".$db." ".$table." --where=date_timestamp^>1433510367 > ".$rep_local.$file." ");